# Quantization Matrices in x264

Tags: c++, x264

I've downloaded the source code and am wading through it --- does anybody know where the QMs  for the images and the residuals are stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of x264 snapshot `20100603-2245/`, they're stored in:

```
common/set.h
```